# How make this graph in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to do this kind of graph in Excel, but nothing so far.
I don't find anything like it, but it has to be this way, not bars.

```
starter         22,58    20,76    7,1      37,93    68,42
professional    72,41    72,73    71,43    70,83    82,86
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your data set. Are they pairs (22, 58) (20, 76) ... or individual numbers (20, 55, 20, 76, ...)?

Comment: @Rhys: I think these are numbers using `,` as decimal seperator, so 22.58, 20.76, 7.1 ... if using `.` as decimal seperator.

Comment: Ah, european numbering. I get it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is called a Scatter plot, which is one of the default options available in Excel. Select your data source(s), go to the Insert tab and in the Charts group select Scatter.

Comment: This does not excatly create the graph, since scatter does not allow the x axis to use groups/series.

Answer (score 3):

For people with the same problems, there is a usefull tool named [FunFun](https://www.funfun.io/1/home), which allows people to use web languages like Html, Css and JavaScript in Excel.

Javascript has a lot of powerful libraries for data visualization, like Charts.js and D3, that you can use with this [Excel add-in](https://www.funfun.io/1/msaddin) to create any chart you want.

If you want to test out different libraries, Funfun hosts an online editor with an embedded spreadsheet, where you can see the output of your code instantly.

I made this chart with Chart.js on the FunFun website that I directly loaded in Excel by pasting the link of the funfun online editor below:

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a2a9c6bcdeaed4cdfca60d3

Here are some screenshots(Website to Excel Add-in):

[image: playground]

[image: load]

[image: code]

[image: final]

Answer (score 0):

I know the question has been marked as answered, but I would still like to link to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/591094/make-a-mixed-bar-and-scatter-graph-with-excel-2010/591136?noredirect=1#comment727162_591136) where the answer also provides a guide on *howto* actually do it in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a range with "Starter" and "Professional" in the first column and two zeros in the second. Insert a bar chart. This provides labels, but the zero means the bars do not show.

In another two columns, place 1 for Starter and 2 for Professional in the first column, and the Y values in the second. Copy this range, select chart, use Paste Special (categories in first column).

Right click on this new series, choose Change Chart Type, select XY Scatter. Again right click on new series, choose Format Data Series, select Primary Axis where given a choice.